# When extending javascript functionality, what is the difference between Number and Math function?

Tags: javascript

I have extended javascripts core functionality by creating a few functions that were useful to me. When creating test cases for a function today I started wondering which way is the best to extend javascripts functionality for integer numbers. Using Number.prototype, or the Math object.

```
Number.prototype.sqr = function () {
    return this * this;
};
var test1 = (6).sqr();
alert("This is 36: " + test1);
```

OR

```
Math.sqr = function (num) {
    return num * num;
};
var test2 = Math.sqr(6);
alert("This is 36: " + test2);
```

These two examples could be switched around for any integer type function that you would like to create, so which should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 'd go with `Math.sqr`, because it doesn't force the reader of the code to think "what is this thing that has an `sqr` member?". Of course in a real program you wouldn't see `(6).sqr()` which might make it clearer what is going on, but rather some variable.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really matter, whatever syntax you prefer.  That's not case when you start messing with Array.prototype or (*GASP*) Object.prototype.

Simply for consistency, I prefer to modify Math since other things like pow, sqrt, sin, etc are in there.